# Create a numpy array from columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
A    B    C
1    2    3
1    5    3
4    8    2
4    2    1
```

I would like to create a `NumPy` array from this data using column `A` as the index, column `B` as the column headers and column `C` as the fill data.

Ultimately, it should look like this:

```
     2    5    8
1    3    3    
4    1         2
```

**Is there a good way to do this?**

I have tried `df.pivot_table`, but I'm worried I have messed up the data, and I would rather do it in another, more intuitive way.

Comment: No, you can't have empty *cells* in an array. Why not fill those empty cells/spaces with some invalid specifier like `0s` or `NaNs` or something else?

Comment: Yup, filling with zeros would work great. I was just going to apply df.fillna(0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

manipulate the dataframe like this

```
df.set_index(['A', 'B']).C.unstack()
```

[image]

Or

```
df.set_index(['A', 'B']).C.unstack(fill_value='')
```

[image]

---

get the numpy array like this

```
df.set_index(['A', 'B']).C.unstack().values

array([[  3.,   3.,  nan],
       [  1.,  nan,   2.]])
```

Or

```
df.set_index(['A', 'B']).C.unstack(fill_value='').values

array([[3, 3, ''],
       [1, '', 2]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Or, `pandas.pivot_table`

Answer (score 1):

`Pandas` unstack looked nice! So, I thought let's try to replicate the same behavior with NumPy that could work on arrays and ended up something like this -

```
def numpy_unstack(a, fillval=0):
    r = np.unique(a[:,0],return_inverse=1)[1]
    c = np.unique(a[:,1],return_inverse=1)[1]
    out = np.full((r.max()+1,c.max()+1),fillval)
    out[r,c] = a[:,2]
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [81]: df
Out[81]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  1  5  3
2  4  8  2
3  4  2  1

In [82]: numpy_unstack(df.values,0)
Out[82]: 
array([[ 3.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  2.]])

In [83]: numpy_unstack(df.values,np.nan)
Out[83]: 
array([[  3.,   3.,  nan],
       [  1.,  nan,   2.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned above, you can use `pd.pivot_table` like

```
In [1655]: df.pivot_table(index='A', columns='B', values='C', fill_value='')
Out[1655]:
B  2  5  8
A
1  3  3
4  1     2
```